# Tracking down a ColdFusion memory leak with JRocket

Tags: java, debugging, coldfusion

We're having a Java Memory issue. Using JRocket I see a char array on the heap that looks like "--->        " (a ColdFusion closing comment marker) taking up 64 Meg. Why is this happening and more importantly how do I track it down and get rid of it?

Update: OK I found where this is occuring but not why. the code in question is where I left a closing comment tag by mistake after a  tag:
" --->"
Why the "--->" would show up in memory I don't know. But the thread memory consumption grows exponetially. Can the JVM perform garbage collection inside a thread? It uses a CFC where everything is assigned to a var local struct. This is CF 8 BTW.

Comment: What version of Java are you on? What version of CF are you on? Have you tried CF Server Monitoring?

Comment: The JVM can perform garbage collection on anything in the heap. If a thread (GC Root) still contains a hard reference to an object though, it will not be collected.  The "--->" is interesting-- perhaps a parser error causing an endless loop.  Are you sure that is the source of the memory leak and not a red herring.  Jrockit has a report for the objects consuming the most heap.  Also, you can view what object counts are trending up the fastest.

Comment: Brad: my response was truncated. the "--->" follows a cfthread declaration so no I don't think it itself is the cause. Something in the thread/loop keeps growing. The thread has a loop and everything in the loop is local var scoped. But jRocket is just showing me the char array (a thread is a char array??) not stuff inside the thread. Maybe I can cfdump the local scope after x interations. The char array with the "--->" (since removed) is whats trending the fastest.

Comment: Brad: I asked if the JVM can perform garbage collection inside a thread. The answer is an emphatic "NO". The thread is protected from GC until it is joined or terminated. Threads use a stack, not heap memory, hence the name of this site

Answer (score 0):

It is more useful to look at

- Large objects such as `<cfquery>` results with lots of rows and columns
- DSNs that have large buffers
- Rapidly repeating large operations. Things like thousands of `<cfquery>`s